# Is it bad to upload a file with an extension like .sh.jpg in FastAPI?

Tags: mime-type

Let's say I have a file named foo.sh.jpg or foo.exe.jpg. FastAPI automatically assigns a `content-type: image/jpeg` in both cases so if you check the MIME type you technically have an image. I wanted to know if by also having a `.sh` extension it could go undetected (if you only check for MIME type) as a .sh and run itself at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad?

Bad is subjective.  MIME type is mostly just a method of telling the browser how to deal with a specific piece of data. `image/jpeg` would be treated as binary, and then an attempt would be made to display said image rather than download.  I am sure this could be over-written ... but given default behavior it would just show as a broken image file in the page.

In terms of file extension, Linux pretty much ignores file extensions and thus `foobar.sh.exe.whocares.jpg.png` wouldnt really matter.  Also, chances are the file itself would not be flagged as executable. So even if a user clicked it ... not much would happen.

In terms of file extensions for windows `foo.sh.exe.is.ignored.only.last.part.is.valid.jpg`. Windows would treat it as a jpg file and when clicked would attempt to open it with whatever is set as the default picture viewer.  If its not a valid image file, that program would most likely give an error of some type.

TLDR; Its bad in the sense that its confusing and would cause people to scratch their heads ... but ultimately wouldnt do anything useful or destructive.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know if I had to check for potentially harmful extensions as well. MIME type seems to be enough.